# Update values in a column of dataframe1 from a dataframe2 where other column values match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update values of a column in a dataframe df1 for isolated rows with values from a second dataframe df2. The shape of df1 and df2 do not match. to select the rows in df1 I have to match column values from df1 and df2.

I succeeded in updating df1 by reading values from df2 into a dictionary and matching the key:values pairs to df1 using the np.where function.

```
# generating a dictionary with key:value pairs from df2 with columnnamesofinterest
columnnamesofinterest = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6']
dict1 = {}
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    for i in df2_columnnamesofinterest:
        d = {i:row[i]}
        dict1 = update(d)

#updating df1['Col6'] with value from df2['Col6'] for selected rows only where values of other/selected columns match 
df1['Col6'] = (np.where((df1['Col1']==dict1['Col1']) & (df1['Col2']==dict1['Col2']) & (df1['Col3']==dict1['Col3']) & (df1['Col3']==dict1['Col3']) & (df1['Col4']==dict1['Col4']) &
(df1['Col5']==dict1['Col5']), dict1['Col6'], ('nomatch')))
```

My problem is, that it takes a very, very long time to finish. 
I was wondering if you know a faster way to selectively update df1 with values from df2.
(I'm basically trying to mimic the 'Update' function from JMP)

Comment: Are you simply looking for `pd.merge`?

Comment: Maybe smarter people than me understand this question but I would say if you could provide a `df1` and `df2` and a "desired outcome" concrete example of your more generalized question, I know somebody could answer it in no time. Are the row counts the same for both dataframes? I know you said the shapes don't match but do the row shapes match?